# Laravel 5.5 link com Ancora

Tags: html5, laravel

Eu tenho a rota abaixo que redireciona para a página principal do meu site..

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'site', 'namespace' => 'site'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index')->name('site');
```

eu queria adicionar uma ancora para a `div` serviços no meu site ficando assim:

```
localhost:8000/site#servicos
```

Como faço isso em Laravel?

Ja tentei:

```
 <a href='{{ route('site') }}#servicos'>Serviços</a>

 <a href='#servicos'>Serviços</a>

 <a href={{ route('site#servicos') }}'>Serviços</a>

 <a href={{ url('site#servicos') }}>'Serviços</a>

 <a href=/site#servicos>'Serviços</a>
```

todas mudam a URL mas não redireciona para a div que preciso, sugestões?

Comment: como assim uma ancora na rota? você quer que sua pagina fala um scroll ate a outra div? é isso?

Comment: sim, uma ancora em um link.... para ir diretamente para a div que está no meio da index no click...

Comment: Bom, o primeiro item deveria funcionar. Pelo menos no meu ambiente funcionou. Tem certeza que a div tem ID?

Comment: @Phiter obrigado.. matou a pau o problema... esqueci do bendito ID!!!!!! obrigado

Comment: Eu já estava com a resposta pronta, rs

Comment: iniciante é fogo rs... as vezes dou uns vacilos kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uma âncora com `#` vai seguir um elemento que tiver o atributo `ID` com o mesmo valor, veja:

```
<a href="#service">Serviços</a>


<div id="service"></div>
```

Comment: obrigado pessoal.. tinha esquecido o bendido ID... kkkkk iniciante é fogo.. rs